# Deferred API calls don't seem to run on normal front end instances

Tags: google-app-engine

when using the deferred api, does the deferred method ( called in my case from the default task queue ) get run on a normal front end instance?

I've got a deferred task running ( definitely running because it is logging frequently ) but there are no instances appearing in the admin console...

Answer (score 3):

Normally they run on a seperate instance. But if your current instance(s) has / have the capacity to serve your deferred task, they will run your task.

You can also configure :

```
deferred.defer(function, ...., _target='1.backend1') # run in a backend
```

Or configure to use available resources :

```
deferred.defer(function, ...., _headers = {'X-AppEngine-FailFast' : 'True'} )
```

Ofcourse it all depend how busy your app is, how your app was configured, how many task you execute, and ....